# SQL Server 2022 Contained AlwaysOn Group - reuse system databases

Tags: alwayson

The following issues I've come across and wanted to let the community know, just incase.

So I have a lab environment, 4 nodes , SQL Server 2022 Enterprise, CU3.
For some reason, if you create the AG group without reusing system databases, the following is missing
msdb.dbo.syssubsystems (This is from your Contain AG group (connect to your listener) - If you look up this table exists at the local instance)

So you can create a job, but when you try to go through the Steps UI, you get the following error:
[image]

---

The current fix at least on my side:
I recreate the AG group with the option to reuse system databases.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Create the AG contained Group with reuse system databases.